# Not able to expand last element while using JqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

Here is my code for grouping, i am binding json object with jqgrid, everything is working fine except the last record . i am not able to expand the last record.

```
            sortname: 'Rounting',
            grouping: true,
            groupingView: {
                groupField: ['Rounting'],
                groupText: ['<b>{0} - {1} Item(s)</b>'],
                groupCollapse: true,
                groupDataSorted: true,
                groupOrder: ['desc']                    

            },
            caption: "Routing information"
```